# What is the correct beta hat matrix when solving for horizontal distance from the point to the fitted line (x regressed on y)?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I am having difficulty reproducing linear regression coefficients from Casella and Berger.
On page 583 figure 12.2.2. He shows two regression lines I am interested in.

(a) a regression of y on x

(b) a regression of x on y

I can get the beta hat matrix for (a), but not for (b).

Here is my work to get (a)

The key is that I am using the following for my beta hat matrix

$$
{\hat{\beta}} = \left(X^\mathsf{T}X\right)^{-1} X^\mathsf{T}Y
$$

```
df <- structure(list(Y = c(3.22, 4.87, 0.12, 2.31, 4.25, 2.24, 2.81, 
3.71, 3.11, 0.9, 4.39, 4.36, 1.26, 3.13, 4.05, 2.28, 3.6, 5.39, 
4.12, 3.16, 4.4, 1.18, 2.54, 4.89), B0 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), B1 = c(3.74, 
3.66, 0.78, 2.4, 2.18, 1.96, 0.2, 2.5, 3.5, 1.35, 2.36, 3.13, 
1.22, 1, 1.29, 0.95, 1.05, 2.92, 1.76, 0.51, 2.17, 1.99, 1.53, 
2.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

Y <- df$Y
B0 <- df$B0 # the intercept
B1 <- df$B1
X <- cbind(B0, B1)
solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
```

For (a) I correctly get $y = 1.86 + .68x$

---

I was assuming that a regression of x on y would just swap the $X$ and $Y$

This would give me the following beta hat matrix:

$$
{\hat{\beta}} = \left(Y^\mathsf{T}Y\right)^{-1} Y^\mathsf{T}X
$$

The problem is that this does not match with the text

```
solve(t(Y)%*%Y)%*%t(Y)%*%X
```

My coefficients are

$y = .27 + .57x$

But the correct values are

$y = -2.31 + 2.82x$

[image]

My question is this:

What is the correct beta hat matrix when solving for horizontal distance from the *point* to
the *fitted line* (x regressed on y)?

---

### Solution

The answer is

$$
{\hat{\beta}} = \left(Y^\mathsf{T}Y\right)^{-1} Y^\mathsf{T}X
$$

I had added an extra column of ones in my X matrix by mistake when I tried to solve (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe has `B1` where it should have `X` and an unnecessary `B0`

Try this instead

```
df <- structure(list(Y = c(3.22, 4.87, 0.12, 2.31, 4.25, 2.24, 2.81, 
3.71, 3.11, 0.9, 4.39, 4.36, 1.26, 3.13, 4.05, 2.28, 3.6, 5.39, 
4.12, 3.16, 4.4, 1.18, 2.54, 4.89),  X = c(3.74, 
3.66, 0.78, 2.4, 2.18, 1.96, 0.2, 2.5, 3.5, 1.35, 2.36, 3.13, 
1.22, 1, 1.29, 0.95, 1.05, 2.92, 1.76, 0.51, 2.17, 1.99, 1.53, 
2.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

X1 <- cbind(1, df$X)
solve(t(X1) %*% X1) %*% t(X1) %*% df$Y
lm(df$Y ~ df$X)
```

which gives your regression line $y = 1.8614 + 0.6763x$ as you found

If you want the regression of $x$ on $y$ then the corresponding code would be

```
Y1 <- cbind(1, df$Y)
solve(t(Y1) %*% Y1) %*% t(Y1) %*% df$X
lm(df$X ~ df$Y)
```

which would give a regression line of $x = 0.8203 + 0.3547y$ and rearranging this would give $y = -2.3124+2.8190 x$

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that my X had an extra column of ones when I tried to solve (b).